# How do I apply a dynamic style in code at runtime?

Tags: .net, wpf, styling

I need to apply a style in code ike this:

```
TextBlock.Style = TryFindResource("MyStyle") as Style;
```

that will be updated dynamically when the resource dictionary is changed (i.e. skin is replaced at runtime). In other words I need the equivalent to using a dynamic resource like this:

```
<TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource MyStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using [SetResourceReference](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/29/how-to-set-a-property-to-a-dynamicresource-reference-in-code/).

```
textBlock.SetResourceReference(TextBlock.StyleProperty, "MyStyle")
```